# Use Entity as property but make it a complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got an entity (A) which stores data in its own table. I want to make this entity a property of another entity (B) but store all of its data in Entity B's table (sort of like a complex type) so I can write the exact values of the entity at that time.

I've tried doing this myself but Entity B always treats entity A as a foreign key even if the property is not virtual, I've also tried inheriting which didn't work correctly. I could make an exact copy of entity A's type and assign to it to solve it but I'm a big DRY fan and feel its just going to add unnecessary complexity.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Code below, I can't post the original code but here's a flavor of what it looks like

```
public class EntityA {

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; } 

    public int prop1 { get; set; }

    public virtual AnotherEntity { get; set; }
}


public class EntityB {

    // foreign key as part of composite key
    // entity C code not included as doesn't
    // affect the problem
    [Key, Column(Order=0)] 
    public int EntityCId { get; set; }   

    public virtual EntityC { get; set; }

    // this is set as part of the composite key
    // as I want to use entity ID but 
    // not make the field foreign key
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public EntityA saveInToEntityBTable { get; set; }     

}
```

Comment: Could we see some code?

Comment: @Zach added some example code, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, what you have to do is abstract a base class that can be inherited. As the base class is abstract it will never create a table so the inheriting classes have no foreign keys to link to.

```
public class EntityA : EntityABase {


}

public abstract class EntityABase {

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; } 

    public int prop1 { get; set; }

    public virtual AnotherEntity { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : EntityABase {

    [Key]  
    public virtual EntityC { get; set; }

}
```

Note: You can use TPC (table per concrete type) if you don't want to use an abstract class but I had problems with migrations not creating the columns or foreign keys for property "AnotherEntity" on EntityB (Entity A created them just fine)

Comment: On a side note, I would call that complex type class **Snapshot to not mix it with entities. e.g. ProductSnapshot if this approach is used on order details for example